# spring security permitAll not working

Tags: java, spring, security, spring-mvc, spring-security

I enable spring security in my system. I have two urls, and one should be without security (for now). 
Here is my security section

```
<security:intercept-url pattern="/api/admin**"
                        access="permitAll" />
<security:intercept-url pattern="/api/**"
                        access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_ADMIN', 'ROLE_USER')" />
<security:http-basic />
```

Admin section should be available without login for now, but that is not the case, accessing url: http://localhost:8080/kma/api/admin/accounting/
Still requires a username and password

Comment: I am a bit baffled here .. I am not seeing any issues when I execute a spring rest mvc project with the exact same config. Are you receiving any error  Check out my code .. https://github.com/ntarunmenon/Hello-World/tree/master/mvcmavenspringrestsecurity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `<security:intercept-url pattern="/api/admin/**" access="permitAll" />`.  Note the `/` after `admin` and before `**`.

Without the `/` the configuration will match requests like `/api/admin`, `/api/admin123`, etc.

Comment: May I draw your attention to my question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33220662/why-is-permitall-not-working)?