# Why is 'permitAll()' not working?

Tags: xml, gwt, spring-security

Mention worthy: I am following a tutorial about [Securing GWT apps with Spring Security](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2010/12/securing-gwt-apps-with-spring-security.html).

---

I don't get this. I can't seem to get `permitAll` to work as I need it to.

This is my current configuration:

```
<http auto-config="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="permitAll" />
    <form-login 
        login-page="/login" 
        default-target-url="/welcome" 
        authentication-failure-url="/login?error" 
        username-parameter="username"
        password-parameter="password" />
</http>
```

If I'm accessing my site on `//localhost:8080` the site gets not entirely loaded because the request

```
//localhost:8080/app/xsrf
```

is `403 Forbidden` for some reason. The way I configured Spring Security should not be the problem here if I understood it correctly.

I **does not** work if I simply add

```
<intercept-url pattern="/**" access="permitAll" />
```

to `<http ..>` what *does* work is adding this:

```
<http pattern="/app/xsrf" security="none"/>
```

I would like to understand why because this is not how I wan to configure Spring Security.. adding every single URL that is supposed to be permitted.

An **additional** problem I am facing is that for whatever reason (perhaps the same) I cannot access `//localhost:8080/login`. Which means If I submit my login to `/login` I am getting `403 Forbidden`.

Now, one would think that adding `<http pattern="/login" security="none"/>` would help here but *no*. If I add that to my configuration I am getting `404 Not Found` on this particular URL.

This starts to drive me insane as I am stuck here for so many days I don't dare to tell you. Your help shall be appreciated and rewarded.

---

Entire **applicationContext-service.xml**

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.xsd">

    <!-- Imports -->
    <beans:import resource="applicationContext-jooq.xml"/>

    <!-- /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// -->
    <!-- // BEGIN Spring Security -->

    <http pattern="/app/xsrf" security="none"/>
    <!-- <http pattern="/login" security="none"/> -->

    <http auto-config="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="permitAll" />

        <form-login 
            login-page="/login" 
            default-target-url="/welcome" 
            authentication-failure-url="/login?error" 
            username-parameter="username"
            password-parameter="password" />
    </http>

    <beans:bean id="authenticationListener" 
            class="com.mz.server.web.auth.CustomAuthenticationListener"/>

    <beans:bean id="authenticationProvider" 
            class="com.mz.server.web.auth.CustomAuthenticationProvider"/>

    <beans:bean id="userDetailsService" 
            class="com.mz.server.web.service.CustomUserDetailsService"/>

    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider ref="authenticationProvider"/>
    </authentication-manager>

    <!-- // END Spring Security -->
    <!-- /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// -->
    <!-- // BEGIN Services -->

    <beans:bean id="loginService" class="com.mz.server.web.service.LoginService">
        <beans:constructor-arg ref="dslContext" />
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- // END Services -->

</beans:beans>
```

---

**Edit:**

Reduced applicationContext-service.xml

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"

    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.xsd">

    <!-- Imports -->
    <beans:import resource="applicationContext-jooq.xml"/>

    <!-- //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// -->
    <!-- // BEGIN Spring Security -->

    <global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled"/>

    <http auto-config="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="permitAll" />
    </http>

    <!-- // END Spring Security-->

</beans:beans>
```

This is the **web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">

    <display-name>GWT Application | mz</display-name>

    <welcome-file-list> <!-- Default page to serve -->
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <!-- //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// -->
    <!-- // BEGIN Filters -->

    <!-- Spring Security -->

    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <!-- // END FILTERS -->
    <!-- //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// -->
    <!-- // BEGIN Listeners -->

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.mz.server.web.ServerConfig</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- // END Listeners -->
    <!-- //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// -->
    <!-- // BEGIN Servlets -->

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>login</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.mz.server.web.servlet.LoginServletImpl</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>login</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/app/login</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>xsrf</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.XsrfTokenServiceServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>xsrf</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/app/xsrf</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet> <!-- Dispatcher Servlet for REST API for Mobile Devices -->
        <servlet-name>mobile-restapi</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>    
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mobile-restapi</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/app/restapi/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- // END Servlets -->
    <!-- //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// -->
    <!-- // BEGIN Context Parameter -->

    <context-param>
        <param-name>
            gwt.xsrf.session_cookie_name
        </param-name>
        <param-value>
            mzsid
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>
            contextConfigLocation
        </param-name>
        <param-value>
            classpath:/**/spring-config.xml
            classpath*:applicationContext-service.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- // END Context Parameter -->
    <!-- //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// -->

</web-app>
```

Comment: It should work with permitAll instead of permitAll(). Does it work with hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN') ?

Comment: Right //localhost:8080/app/login should work with permitAll.

Comment: Do you have anything else set up in the security context? For example custom filters and such? permitAll() means that every request is allowed, but security is not disabled. So, if you have a filter which fails, authentication will fail.

Comment: @StefanFalk Just as a test, have you tried to see what happens when you explicitly set authorization to "permitAll" for the path "/app/login"?

Comment: @StefanFalk your configuration looks correct to me, I can't see any reason why it doesn't work. Only thing popping in my mind is that there might be an error in the authentication beans you injected (listener, auth provider or auth manager)

Comment: What do the logs look like? Are you performing a GET or a POST when you get a forbidden? If you are performing a POST, did you ensure to include a CSRF token? http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.x/reference/htmlsingle/#csrf-include-csrf-token Alternatively, you can disable (not recommended) CSRF protection http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.x/reference/htmlsingle/#csrf-configure

Comment: Is it possible for you to post a sample somewhere?  The configuration looks correct so the problem looks to be in the application.

Comment: @manish What parts would you need? I am not sure what could cause this problem. I'm basically following that tutorial mentioned in my question but if you can tell me which part you're interested in I can add the code to my question. :)

Comment: @RobWinch I am going to add the logs asap!

Comment: @Stefan, having access to your sample app will be useful.  Even if you are following a guide, it will be less time consuming to have the app where you are facing the problem and debugging it directly rather than creating a sample app from scratch using the same guide.  Additionally, you may have followed certain steps that will not be obvious to us.  Since you claim to be following a guide, it should be easy for you to share your sample app as a ZIP file since it should contain public code any way.

Comment: @manish Unfortunately it is not that easy because I am integrating this into a larger application. But I will try to strip it down to a smaller working example that hopefully reproduces this issue later that day or maybe tomorrow (I'm quite busy atm) but I will let you know when I got it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears that the error was in **web.xml**. Instead of `<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>` (as stated in the tutorial I was following) it should be `/**`:

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <!-- It appears that this should say '/**' and not '/*' as stated in many
        tutorials 
        (e.g. http://websystique.com/spring-security/spring-security-4-hello-world-annotation-xml-example/).  -->
    <url-pattern>/**</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Interestingly is that I'm now getting the following "*INFO*":

```
INFO: Suspicious url pattern: "/**" in context [] - see section SRV.11.2 of the Servlet specification
```

All I can say is that this is starting to feel personal ..

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**
since `use-expressions=true` is enabled by default, so this answer does not help.
But...i found your error:
spring automatically generates a default login page at /login, but only if you dont specify any `login-page` parameter. you set the parameter to `/login`, expecting that you would be redirected to this default page.
and thats why you got the 404 not found error.
so remove the `login-page="/login"` to use the default or create your own login page.
same for the `authentication-failure-url="/login?error"`: remove it when using the default page.
username- and password-parameter in the default login page are "j_username" and "j_password" and spring wouldnt find these. remove them if you dont use your own loginpage...
also you added the xml namespace for security twice...you should remove `xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"`

*only applies to spring security 3.x*
if you want to use expressions like `permitAll` you need to enable them with `use-expressions="true"`. 
dont forget to allow access to the resources required by your loginpage.
[here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#el-common-built-in) you can find some help for the use of expressions.
my question is if you are using a seperate login.jsp/html page or "/login" refers to a place/historytoken in your gwt app?

small example of how it could work:

```
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/resources/**" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isFullyAuthenticated()" />
    <!-- if you are not completely familiar how to use expressions -->
    <!-- then using this will probably easier: -->
    <!-- <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="false">
        <!-- <intercept-url pattern="/login" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" /> -->
        <!-- <intercept-url pattern="/resources/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" /> -->
        <!-- <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" /> -->

    <!-- why not your /index.html/jsp?? -->
    <form-login 
        default-target-url="/welcome" 
        always-use-default-target="true"/>
</http>
```

Comment: use-expressions="true" is set by default in Spring Security 4+ See http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/migrate/current/3-to-4/html5/migrate-3-to-4-xml.html#m3to4-xmlnamespace-http

Comment: @RobWinch oh well you're right. I just saw it here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#el-access-web

Comment: I have removed `xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"` and I now only have one `<intercept-url pattern="/**" ../>` (see edit) but it's still not working. :/ I didn't had time the last weeks to work on this, thus the late answer. Sorry about that.